# Problema para executar select com sequelize

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sequelize-js

Estou tendo problema para executar um select no Nodejs onde o mesmo demora bastante parecendo que o mesmo fica em loop infinito.

module - sequelizejs
bd - SQL server

**dbConnection**

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

    var teste = new Sequelize('bd_name', 'user_name', 'password', {
            host: 'ip_server',
            dialect: 'mssql'
          });
    
        }

teste.authenticate()
.then(()=>{
    console.log('Conexão estabelecida com sucesso.');
    
})
.catch(err=>{
    console.error('Erro na conexão com o banco de dados:', err);
});      
        
    module.exports = function() {
        return teste; 
     }
```

**FormulasDAO**

```js
function FormulasDAO(connection) {
    this._connection = connection;
}

FormulasDAO.prototype.getFormulas = function(callback){
    this._connection.query('select * from USUARIO', callback);
}


module.exports = function() {
    return FormulasDAO;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual o tamanho da sua tabela `USUARIO`? Se tiver muitas linhas e colunas pode ser que a `query` seja demorada mesmo

Comment: @Sorack tem exatamente 280 registros